# Query iSCSI ID of a device node on Linux?

Tags: linux, iscsi

I have some iSCSI targets mounted on a linux host as /dev/sd*.  How can I query the iSCSI ID from the device node?

This is on CentOS 5, using the `iscsi-initiator-utils` package.

Comment: Does `lsscsi --verbose` give you this information (haven't played with iSCSI much)?

Comment: Doesn't seem to.  There's also a --long option, but no joy there either.  It prints handy paths into /sys for the device, but I can't see any iSCSI IDs in there either.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look into

```
 /dev/disk/by-path/
```

you should see links to your devices

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I didn't know that.

Answer (score 4):

```
iscsiadm --mode session -P 3
```

That will produce lots of extraneous output. You care about the *Target* line that comes before the *Attached scsi disk* line for the device in question.

Comment: Yep, that works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can get the ID by issuing `iscsiadm  -m discovery -t st -p <target-ip>`.

Comment: Unfortunately that command only lists all IDs for a server, it doesn't let me match them up with local device nodes.